# Pushpad or Web push notification how to custom dialog message

Tags: web-push, pushpad

This is default dialog.
[image]

How to custom permission dialog look like this

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no additional info can be added to the default dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, those custom dialogs are normal HTML overlays.
Even if you use a custom dialog, the next step would be to display the default dialog. To ask for notification-permission using javascript, that default dialog is the only way to go. 
Sadly there is nothing one can do about it.

Hope this clarifies your doubts :)